# How to add sql script using installshield?

Tags: installshield

How can I add sqlscripts to installshield- visual studio 2013, so it runs when while deploying?
Any help would be very appriciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I Installed Installsheild LE, Added all necessary files and was able to run the MSI successfully, but couldnt find a place where I can add .bat file.

Comment: google for Custom Action, and write an answer if you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to my own question.
In installation designer select sql script, Add new sql connection and add new script to it